# Why is the /d flag not working with xcopy?

Tags: windows, xcopy

Am I going crazy? I'm trying to copy logfiles that were generated today:

`xcopy i:\logs c:\logs /d:05-02-2012`

It's copying zero files even though there should be some files modified today. What am I missing?

Windows Server 2008 and Windows XP Pro, PowerShell and DOS Command Prompt.

Comment: That didn't work, but adding the /e flag seems to have worked! There is a directory structure beneath \logs which I forgot to mention :)

Comment: Have you verified that there *are* files from today?

Comment: Don's problem was just that XCOPY was only working on the root directory (no subfolders) as it lacked a "/e" or "/s" switch, so it *was* indeed only copying log files generated today, but it was also only limited to the top level (which contained no log files).